# POST request android app using volley to local Microsft server with API (.net core)

Tags: android, api, post

so i'm trying to make a login-page we're users can fill in there username & password to login and make a new account if they don't have one. see picture here => [login form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv22r.png) now when i click the button to POST the username & password from android to my server it shut down with volley code 400. and when i try the same post with postman it does work. can't find a anwser to fix it. please help!

Here is a snap of my [api code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O44Em.png)
& from my android code: [part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBvAC.png) / [part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1gGt.png)

Comment: post the volley petition...

Comment: where do i find volley petition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, had to do with getparams